# Have express.js send response from async callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I have a pretty simple scenario, with a RESTful endpoint in Node / Express.js that needs to invoke another REST service and return its result.

The trouble I'm facing is getting the response in the Express method to send the appropriate data back.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    async.series([ function(callback) {
        var httpConfig = app.config.evaluateRuleService;
        logger.info("About to make request");
        // make an async call here
        require('../utils/http-wrapper/http').post(req.body, httpConfig,
                function(err, data) {
                    logger.info("still have res: " + res);
                    logger.info("Got response: " + data);
                    // data.isAuthorized is set by the service being invoked
                    callback(false, data);
                });
    } ],
    function(err, results) {
        logger.info("Inside collate method");
        // correctly gets invoked after async call completes
        // but res.json isn't sending anything to the client
        res.json({
            authorized : results.isAuthorized
        });
    })
    // Problem: The client is receiving the response before the async call completes
});
```

Here's the log output:

```
"Listening on port 8897","time":"2015-03-27T19:22:24.435Z","v":0}
"About to make request","time":"2015-03-27T19:22:30.608Z","v":0}
fetch() POST http://localhost:8897/test 
**<logs of the server method being invoked are printed out>** 
"still have res: [object Object]","time":"2015-03-27T19:22:30.616Z","v":0} 
"Got response: {\"isAuthorized\":true}","time":"2015-03-27T19:22:30.616Z","v":0}
"Inside collate method","time":"2015-03-27T19:22:30.617Z","v":0}
```

So the order occurs in an agreeable way, however, the clients invoking this endpoint are seeing an empty result being returned, and not the expected `authorized : results.isAuthorized` which I'm trying to send to the response in the last callback.

Much thanks

**Edit with solution:**

As Peter and Kevin point out, there were two issues going on, and it was a misdiagnosis to think the response was sending too early.

The `results` object is indeed an array, and my relevant index is `[0]`.  Then I needed to convert the `String response` as a JSON object to be able to access the fields I need.

The answer in the callback function that solves this is:

```
function(err, results) {
    logger.info('Inside collate method');
    // Need to access array at appropriate index 
    logger.info('Authorize Response: ' + results[0]);
    // Need to parse the value at index 0 as a JSON object
    var authorizeResponse = JSON.parse(results[0]);
    res.json({
            authorized : authorizeResponse.isAuthorized
        });
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are passing isAuthorized to the callback of async.series

Comment: I shortened the code a little to make the flow a little more evident and that part got cropped.  I'll update it to make it clear

Comment: And the code works-- debugging it i know `results.isAuthorized` is appropriately populated, and the logging statements support this as well.  The issue is the response is being sent to the client before the `res.json({...` line is invoked.

Comment: *"The issue is the response is being sent to the client before the `res.json({...` line is invoked. "* That shouldn't be possible, i think you are misdiagnosing the problem. It's more likely that `results` doesn't have an `isAuthorized` property at that point.

Comment: Have you logged `result` in the async.series callback? I would expect it to be an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the correct signature for async.series. The arguments to the final callback are `error, arrayOfResults`, so you need `results[0].isAuthorized` to get the correct value. My theory is your code generates the object `{isAuthorized: undefined}` because the array of results has no `isAuthorized` property. This then serializes to an empty object in JSON as shown below:

```
> JSON.stringify({isAuthorized: undefined})
'{}'
```

The timing and control flow are otherwise OK though. The problem is not the response being sent too early.

Comment: You're right on all points-- the `results` object is an array, and referencing `results[0]` was the first part I had wrong.  Then you're also right on the plain string-to-object conversion I needed.  I updated my answer to show both incorporated and clarify the misdiagnosis for future people who may see this